# When adding permissions to User - ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: django, django-models, django-permissions

I created a custom user and add permission `is_driver` to check whether my user belongs to `Driver's Group`.

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("is_driver", "Can access driver's page")
        )
```

But when I run `manage.py makemigrations` and then `manage.py migrate`, it throws an error: `ValueError: too many values to unpack`.
I'm new to permissions, maybe there is some other way to add permissions to a `Group`. What's wrong?

Answer (score 24):

Try to add the missing `,` at the end of your tuple

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("is_driver", "Can access driver's page"),
        )
```

Python is strict about that when a `tuple` only has one item. To see what happens at Python level you could open the shell and try the following.

```
>>> foo = (('ham', 'eggs'))
>>> foo
('ham', 'eggs')
>>> foo[0]
'ham'
>>> foo = (('ham', 'eggs'),)
>>> foo
(('ham', 'eggs'),)
>>> foo[0]
('ham', 'eggs')
```

Long story short, without the `,` it is a different data structure.